# Passing arguments to another process as they were entered on the command line with a bash script

Tags: bash, docker

Not sure I've titled this well since I was unable to find an answer I'm really happy with using similar terms, but here goes.

Here's the situation, we're running some services in docker containers and they're all on their own sort of VLAN.  Docker conveniently adds entries for the various containers so that the application can resolve the other addresses from their container name.  E.g. I have a container named application and a container named devsql running a mysql server.  If I use exec to run `ping devsql` from application container, it resolves fine and pings it.  However, if I run `ping devsql` from the host, it has no idea what that is.

Our application is a laravel application and we write migrations that we then use the 'artisan' script to perform.  Normally, this looks like `php artisan migrate`.  However, the config uses devsql as the address for the mysql server, which is fine for the container but the host can't resolve this, so the migration throws an error.

Our solution is to run it from a utility container also on the vlan, so the equivalent commands would be `docker run -it --rm --network=environment_network -v /var/www/html/whatever:/whatever util -c "cd /whatever && php artisan migrate"`  Obviously this is at best cumbersome and at worst is one more thing to confuse new hires.  So I wanted to wrap it in a script.

I wanted the script to work as though you were running the regular php.  For the above example, it's pretty easy, but I want it to handle for example `php -r "echo 'lol'";`.  I don't want uses to have to know that they need to account for it being expanded multiple times.  I've got a script that works, but I'm not sure how brittle it is and I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# echo "cd /pwd && php $@"

# Assume that any argument with spaces in it was quoted (really not sure how great an assumption this
# is, but it's worked well in test).  Bash already expanded the string when parsing the command to call
# this script, but we want this to be a seamless experience for the user and they shouldn't have to know
# that it will be expanded twice, so we need to put quotes back around it.  Since we don't want to
# expand it here either, we surround it with single quotes to pass it to the docker container without
# expansion

x=()
for i in "$@"
do
        if [[ $i =~ [[:space:]] ]]
        then
                x+=\'$i\'' '
        else
                x+=$i' '
        fi
done

#echo "cd /pwd && php $x"

docker run -it --rm --network=environment_network -v $PWD:/pwd util -c "cd /pwd && php $x"
```

I just get a strong code smell off that assumption and it feels like a hack and that there must be a better, more robust way to accomplish this.  Or that my assumption is poor and that something I didn't think of will break it.

I guess my question is, is there a built in construct to pass through the arguments in the way that I want?  Or do you see obvious flaws in my assumption?

Comment: not just `docker run .... && php "${@}"`? Good luck.

Comment: That does work, but the arguments will have been expanded already.  I'd like if possible to pass it to the container to expand, but do it in a way that the user doesn't have to know that it will be parsed twice.  Unless that's different from "$@", I think yours is just the more explicit version of the syntax, no?  I'm pretty new at bash.

Comment: Have to admit, I'm not totally sure this is possible as I think the first shell will expand those before it ever gets to the script and the script will never, ever see the quotes unless they're escaped.  So maybe this sort of hack is the best I can do.

Comment: @BytePorter They are expanded by the shell *before* the script is entered. `"$@"` contains *exactly* what the shell receives, regardless of what expressions were used to set the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-w` option to change working dir, use separate argument for the command (`php`) and drop all the quoting magic:

```
docker run -it [other docker options] -w /pwd util php "$@"
```

That implies you have no ENTRYPOINT in the image (or that ENTRYPOINT can handle all those arguments). Otherwise, use `--entrypoint /path/to/php` instead of specifying `php` as the command.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I had to be making that harder than it should be, I was just thinking I had to recreate the original expression for some reason.  The entrypoint is just the shell with some tricks I copied from the entrypoint.sh script in the official MariaDB image.